# Generic binary operation in a class definition?

Tags: python, class

I am writing a tiny linear algebra module in Python 3, and there are a number of binary operators to define. Since each definition of a binary operator is essentially the same with only the operator itself changed, I would like to save some work by writing a generic binary operator definition only once.

For example:

```
class Vector(tuple):
    def __new__(self, x):
        super().__new__(x)

    # Binary operators

    def __add__(self, xs):
        try:
            return Vector(a + x for a, x in zip(self, xs)))
        except:
            return Vector(a + x for a in self)

    def __and__(self, xs):
        try:
            return Vector(a & x for a, x in zip(self, xs))
        except:
            return Vector(a & x for a in self)

    ... # mul, div, or, sub, and all other binary operations
```

The binary operators above all have the same form. Only the operator is changed. I wonder if I could instead write all operators at once, something like this:

```
def __bop__(self, xs):
    bop = get_bop_somehow()
    try:
        return Vector(bop(a, x) for a, x in zip(self, xs)))
    except:
        return Vector(bop(a, x) for a in self)
```

I've heard that Python can do magical things with the `__getattr__` method, which I tried to use to extract the name of the operator like so:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    print('Method name:', name.strip('_'))
```

But, unfortunately, this only works when called using the full method name, not when an operator is used. How can I write a one-size-fits-all binary operator definition?

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`. Which error do you expect to be raised that switching from `zip(self, xs)` to `self` will fix? Catch that error, and no others.

Comment: I've added an inheritance based approach to my answer if you have to repeat this structure in multiple classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class decorator to mutate your class and add them all in with the help of a factory function:

```
import operator

def natural_binary_operators(cls):
    for name, op in {
        '__add__': operator.add,
        '__sub__': operator.sub,
        '__mul__': operator.mul,
        '__truediv__': operator.truediv,
        '__floordiv__': operator.floordiv,
        '__and__': operator.and_,
        '__or__': operator.or_,
        '__xor__': operator.xor
    }.items():
        setattr(cls, name, cls._make_binop(op))

    return cls


@natural_binary_operators
class Vector(tuple):
    @classmethod
    def _make_binop(cls, operator):
        def binop(self, other):
            try:
                return cls([operator(a, x) for a, x in zip(self, other)])
            except:
                return cls([operator(a, other) for a in self])

        return binop
```

There are a few other ways to do this, but the general idea is still the same.

Comment: You beat me! (and your solution might be better too...)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `operator` module, which gives you functional versions of the operators. For example, `operator.and_(a, b)` is the same as `a & b`.

So `return Vector(a + x for a in self)` becomes `return Vector(op(a, x) for a in self)` and you can parameterize `op`. You still need to define all of the magic methods, but they can be simple pass-throughs.

Comment: I'm aware that the `operator` module provides the operators in function form. What I'd like to know is how to write my class in such a way that the name of the operator can be determined at runtime, without me having to write definitions for each of the operators, even if they just take the form `def __add__(self, x): return self.__bop__(operator.add, x)` (which is still an improvement, I think).

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

This might be super-slow, but you can create an abstract class with all of the binary methods and inherit from it.

```
import operator

def binary_methods(cls):
    operator_list = (
        '__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__', '__truediv__', 
        '__floordiv__', '__and__', '__or__', '__xor__'
    )

    for name in operator_list:
        bop = getattr(operator, name)
        method = cls.__create_binary_method__(bop)
        setattr(cls, name, method)

    return cls

@binary_methods
class AbstractBinary:
    @classmethod
    def __create_binary_method__(cls, bop):
        def binary_method(self, xs):
            try:
                return self.__class__(bop(a, x) for a, x in zip(self, xs))
            except:
                return self.__class__(bop(a, x) for a in self)
        return binary_method

class Vector(AbstractBinary, tuple):
    def __new__(self, x):
        return super(self, Vector).__new__(Vector, x)
```

---

### Original:

Okay, I think I've got a working solution (only tested in Python 2.X) that uses a class decorator to dynamically create the binary methods.

```
import operator

def add_methods(cls):
    operator_list = ('__add__', '__and__', '__mul__')

    for name in operator_list:
        func = getattr(operator, name)
        # func needs to be a default argument to avoid the late-binding closure issue
        method = lambda self, xs, func=func: cls.__bop__(self, func, xs)
        setattr(cls, name, method)

    return cls

@add_methods
class Vector(tuple):
    def __new__(self, x):
        return super(self, Vector).__new__(Vector, x)

    def __bop__(self, bop, xs):
        try:
            return Vector(bop(a, x) for a, x in zip(self, xs))
        except:
            return Vector(bop(a, x) for a in self)
```

Here's some example usage:

```
v1 = Vector((1,2,3))
v2 = Vector((3,4,5))

print v1 * v2 
# (3, 8, 15)
```

Comment: Very nice. I appreciate your use of a mix-in class. Unfortunately, sportsmanship and chivalry and such dictate that I select Blender's five-minute earlier response as the correct one, but please take my +1 and my gratitude.

Comment: @castle-bravo: It doesn't really matter who posted earlier. Select the answer that you find most useful.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do magical things with `__getattr__`, but if you can avoid doing so then I would - it starts to get complicated! In this situation you'd likely need to overwrite `__getattribute__`, but please don't because you will bite yourself in the seat of your own pants if you start messing around with `__getattribute__`.

You can achieve this in a very simple way, by simply defining the first one, and then doing `__and__ = __add__` in the other functions.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def comparison_1(self, thing):
        return self is not thing

    comparison_2 = comparison_1


A = MyClass()

print A.comparison_1(None)
print A.comparison_2(None)
print A.comparison_1(A)
print A.comparison_2(A)
```

gives

```
$ python tmp_x.py 
True
True
False
False
```

However, I'm not a fan of this kind of hackery. I would just do

```
class MyClass(object):
    def comparison_1(self, thing):
        "Compares this thing and another thing"
        return self is not thing

    def comparison_2(self, thing):
        "compares this thing and another thing as well"
        return self.comparison_1(thing)
```

Better to write the extra couple of lines for clarity.

## EDIT:

So I tried it with `__getattribute__`, doesn't work :/. I admit I don't know why.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def add(self, other):
        print self, other
        return None

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == '__add__':
            attr = 'add'

        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)


X = MyClass()
print X.__add__
X + X
```

Doesn't work :/

```
andy@batman[18:15:12]:~$ p tmp_x.py 
<bound method MyClass.add of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f52932ea450>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp_x.py", line 15, in <module>
    X + X
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MyClass' and 'MyClass'
```

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I tried to do with `__getattr__`. It works fine if you call `myobject.__add__(1)`, but not if you use the operator like so: `myobject + 1`. This question is essentially about that.